Oracle PL SQL Insert Statement - ORA-01007: variable not in select list
I have a script that copies records meeting a specific condition to a temporary table.  The original table is then truncated and the records are copied back.
The statement used to create the temporary table is;
create table ARCHIVE_TMP as select * from ORIGINAL_TABLE where TIMESTAMP_UPDATED < '2017-10-04'

And the statement to copy the records back again is;
insert /*+ APPEND */ into ORIGINAL_TABLE select * from ARCHIVE_TMP

When the 2nd line is executed in the script it raises the exception ORA-01007: variable not in select list but if I manually run the 2nd statement it works as expected.
I have checked the user has CREATE and INSERT privileges as there was a problem previously where the privileges were assigned to a role instead of the user.
I have also tried specifying the column names in the select statement instead of using select * but this didn't help.
Following is the entire script;
create or replace procedure TRUNCATE_EXPIRED_ARCHIVE_DATA
(
    p_retention_period      in number   := 84, 
)
as
begin
    declare
        cursor table_cursor is
            select      owner, table_name, column_name, data_type
            from        all_tab_columns
            where       table_name like '%!_A' escape '!'
                        and column_name like 'TIMESTAMP!_%' escape '!'
            group by    owner, table_name, column_name, data_type           
            order by    table_name, column_name;
        RetentionDt     date := null;
        ExpiredCount    number := 0;
        InsertedCount   number := 0;
        TableExists     number := 0;
        ExpiredSql      varchar2(500);
        SelectSql       varchar2(800);
        SqlStmt         varchar2(1300);
    begin
        RetentionDt := add_months(sysdate, p_retention_period * -1);
        for table_rec in table_cursor loop
            begin
                -- Check if there are any expired records...
                SelectSql := 'select count(*) from ' || table_rec.owner || '.' || table_rec.table_name;
                ExpiredSql := ' where ' || table_rec.column_name || ' < ''' || RetentionDt || '''';
                SqlStmt := SelectSql || ExpiredSql;
                execute immediate SqlStmt into ExpiredCount;
                if (ExpiredCount > 0) then
                    -- Drop the temporary table if it already exists...
                    SelectSql := 'select count(*) from tab where tname = ''ARCHIVE_TMP''';
                    execute immediate SelectSql into TableExists;
                    if (TableExists > 0) then
                        SelectSql := 'drop table REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP';
                        execute immediate SelectSql;
                    end if;
                    -- Transfer the records to be retained to the temporary table...
                    SelectSql := 'create table REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP as select * from ' || table_rec.owner || '.' || table_rec.table_name || ' where ' || table_rec.column_name || ' >= ''' || to_char(RetentionDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''';
                    execute immediate SelectSql;
                    InsertedCount := sql%rowcount;
                    commit;
                    if (InsertedCount > 0) then
                        SelectSql := 'truncate table ' || table_rec.owner || '.' || table_rec.table_name;
                        dbms_output.put_line('Truncate Table    : ' || SelectSql);
                        execute immediate SelectSql;
                        SelectSql := 'insert /*+ APPEND */ into ' || table_rec.owner || '.' || table_rec.table_name || ' select * from REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP';
                        execute immediate SelectSql into InsertedCount;
                        commit;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end;
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/


Please [edit] the question to include the script that you are using and the full error message (including line numbers). Debugging code we cannot see is difficult and there may be many things that could cause the issue (i.e. your statements are missing statement terminators that would be needed by a script) and without additional context you may not get a solution.

Your code works without errors fiddle

@MT0 Added the script for the stored procedure. Does dbFiddle run each statement separately or as a script?

SelectSql := 'insert /*+ APPEND */ into ' || table_rec.owner || '.' || table_rec.table_name || ' select * from REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP';
execute immediate SelectSql into InsertedCount;

Is an INSERT (and not a SELECT) so you do not want to have an INTO clause.
You can simplify the procedure to:
create or replace procedure TRUNCATE_EXPIRED_ARCHIVE_DATA
(
    p_retention_period      in number   := 84
)
as
  TABLE_NOT_FOUND EXCEPTION;
  RetentionDt     date := add_months(TRUNC(sysdate), -p_retention_period);
  ExpiredCount    number := 0;
  InsertedCount   number := 0;

  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_NOT_FOUND, -942);
begin
  for table_rec in (
    select      owner, table_name, column_name, data_type
    from        all_tab_columns
    where       table_name like '%!_A' escape '!'
    and         column_name like 'TIMESTAMP!_%' escape '!'
    order by    table_name, column_name
  ) loop
    -- Check if there are any expired records...
    execute immediate
         'select count(*)'
      || ' from "' || table_rec.owner || '"."' || table_rec.table_name || '"'
      || ' where "' || table_rec.column_name || '" < :1'
      INTO ExpiredCount
      USING RetentionDt;
    IF ExpiredCount = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        '"' || table_rec.owner || '"."' || table_rec.table_name || '" Not found'
      );
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
      execute immediate 'drop table REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN TABLE_NOT_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
    END;
    execute immediate
         'create table REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP as'
      || ' select * from "' || table_rec.owner || '"."' || table_rec.table_name || '"'
      || ' where "' || table_rec.column_name || '"'
      || ' >= TIMESTAMP ''' || TO_CHAR(RetentionDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '''';

    InsertedCount := sql%rowcount;
    commit;

    if InsertedCount > 0 then
      execute immediate 'truncate table "' || table_rec.owner || '"."' || table_rec.table_name || '"';
      execute immediate
           'insert /*+ APPEND */ into "' || table_rec.owner || '"."' || table_rec.table_name || '"'
        || ' select * from REODT_PROD.ARCHIVE_TMP';
      commit;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/

fiddle

Thanks @MTO - that fixed the problem.
